# Calling Image.FromFile throws Out of memory exception

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, out-of-memory

**I have a function that fill data grid view and this function use paging** 



```
page size = 30
```



**It's work fine until page 9 throw out of memory exception**

**I have windows server 2008 R2 64 bit,8 GB RAM**

```
public static void FillDataGrid(DataGridView dataGrid, int intPageSize, int intPageIndex, out int intTotal
        ,string title)
    {

         dataGrid.Rows.Clear();

        try
        {
            var dt = GetData(intPageSize, intPageIndex, out intTotal, title); //dt type DataTable
            var dicrectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

            for (var i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                    var uri = new Uri(dt.Rows[i]["URL"].ToString());
                    var host = uri.Host.Replace("www.", "");
                    host = host.Replace(".com", "");

                    var iconFullUrl = dicrectory + @"\Icons\" +
                                      dt.Rows[i]["IconURL"].ToString();
                    object[] row = new object[10];
                    row[0] = "False";
                    row[1] = Image.FromFile(iconFullUrl);
                    row[2] = dt.Rows[i]["Title"].ToString();
                    row[3] = host;
                    row[4] = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i]["Date"].ToString()).ToShortDateString();
                    row[5] = "";
                    row[6] = dt.Rows[i]["URL"].ToString();
                    row[7] = "";
                    row[8] = "";
                    row[9] = dt.Rows[i]["Id"].ToString();

                    dataGrid.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

**in this section of code the error occur**


```
 row[1] = Image.FromFile(iconFullUrl);
```

Comment: According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5(v=vs.110).aspx) the OutOfMemory error can be caused by the file not having a valid image format or GDI+ does not support the pixel format of the file. Also as long as the image is not disposed the file will be marked as inuse.

Comment: Yes Thank You this is the problem how could i mark this as answer ? :D

Comment: I will add as an answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409156/asp-net-creating-thumbails-server-side

Comment: You should remove that try/catch block. It has no effect other than to mess up your stack trace (it will look like the exception came from the line of the "throw").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding my Comment as an Answer:

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the OutOfMemory error can be caused by the file not having a valid image format or because GDI+ does not support the pixel format of the file.

Also as long as the image is not disposed the file will be marked as inuse